# Should I use an NSString const* to define a UILabel text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, constants

Say I have the below label text assignment:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *blah;
.
.
.
[blah setText:@"Blah"];
```

What is wrong with me assigning the text directly here (this is not a localized string) instead of me having a constant up top defining it, as in :

```
NSString const* kBlahLabelText = @"Blah";
.
.
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *blah;
.
.
.
[blah setText:kBlahText];
```

Is there any particular memory reason / readability issue why the latter is better?

What if we were using `dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier`? Should my cell Identifier be a constant then? Or if I was referring to a `UIStoryboard name`? I personally always feel that it is better to have them inline as in the former case above. But I would like to have a good argument as to why, more than a personal preference.

Just as an add on, when I assign `kBlahText` to the label, does the compiler copy `kBlahText` and add it to the label or does it simply change a reference inside?

Comment: If you don't need it localized and aren't keeping all string literals in one place to facilitate maintenance or some such then there's no reason to not just use the string literals inline, vs declaring them as `const` vars or whatever.  The compiler "pools" string literals, so using `@"Blah"` twelve different places is no more expensive in time or storage than using a single `const` var.  ("Readability" issues are in the eyes/mind of the beholder, of course, so you need to evaluate those with your own criteria.)

Comment: `NSString const* kBlahLabelText` is equal to `NSString * kBlahLabelText`, since `NSString` object is not mutable. `NSString * const kBlahLabelText` will prevent `kBlahLabelText` from being assigned to another string value. If you don't change its value somewhere else, you can just use `NSString * kBlahLabelText`.

Comment: To the last question, `UILabel` always copy your `NSString`. You can see it in the header file `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text`.

Comment: Unless you are using this string in several places there is no need to define that string as global constant string. if you use it lots of places then you may declare it globally for better readability & avoid typing error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If anyone of you wants to post an answer, I'll accept it.